# Dynamic vue componenet spread props composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I am using nuxt3 which is consuming a headless cms via graphql, from the cms we get "blocks" of content that make up a page, the response looks similar to this,

```
{
  "id": "73",
  "image": [
    {
      "id": "70",
      "__typename": "blogAssets_Asset"
    }
  ],
  "size": "large",
  "subtitle": null,
  "heading": "Test Hero",
  "reviewsWidget": [],
  "alignment": "fullPageWidth",
  "siteHandle": "default",
  "typeHandle": "hero",
  "__typename": "builder_hero_BlockType"
}
```

In a loop I am wanting to do something like this,

but ideally in the component I want devs to know what component should/could contain for each component, in composition api I believe that I set the props like this,

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    const props = withDefaults(
        defineProps<{
            data: Object
        }>(),
        {}
    );
</script>
```

Is there a way I can be more explicit, so it would be something like?

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    const props = withDefaults(
        defineProps<{
            title: String,
            subtitle: String,
            ...,
            ...
        }>(),
        {}
    );
</script>
```

So just my looking at the props we know this component has a title, subtitle etc etc? Basically is possible to spread the props object?

Comment: You probably need [Binding Multiple Properties Using an Object](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)

Answer (score 0):

The example for your explicit prop would require passing each property of the object as a separate prop to the component. Assuming you want the full object passed as one prop I would suggest either,

##### Creating a custom type

For example if the incoming prop object will have properties `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`, we can create a new type called `Person` containing these properties which we can then assign to the prop instead of the much more generic type `Object`

```js
export interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    myData: Person;
  }>(),
  {}
);
```

##### Setting a default value

Can be done in addition to creating a new type, or used by itself. The idea is that setting a default value means listing each object key you expect to receive and setting an initial empty/null value, which will additionally inform other developers about what object properties to expect.

```js
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    myData: object;
  }>(),
  {
    myData: () => {
      return {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        age: 0
      };
    }
  }
);
```